# Parse XML file and display on QML ListView

Tags: c++, xml, listview, qml, qt5

I am new to QML. I am struggling with this problem.
I have an XML file containing a list of Patient's information. How do I display the patient's information on a ListView, each patient is displayed on one item of the ListView as shown on the picture below.
Thank you!

The XML file look like this:
[image: patients.xml]

[image: ListView]

Comment: I recommend parsing the file in C++ code and creating a QAbstractListModel with your data.

Comment: There is also https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/qml-qtqml-xmllistmodel-xmllistmodel.html but never used it.

Comment: Could you provide your data set as text instead of an image?

Comment: As already said above, there is [XmlListModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-xmllistmodel-xmllistmodel.html) that allows you to do exactly what you need.